# How to install Jupyter extensions on Azure Machine Learning Notebooks?

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I created a virtual machine on Azure Machine Learning and I'm running a simple jupyter notebook. I would like to install the jupyter extensions since I really need the collapsible titles but it seem it isn't working. I tried with pip install and it's already installed but the menu does not appear...

Answer (score 2):

There are some good [JupyterLab extensions](https://github.com/mauhai/awesome-jupyterlab) out there, and if you want to use them in AML Compute Instances JupyterLab. Foremost the [Table of Contents](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-toc) extension which can be a great help with larger notebooks.